# Express error middleware not reached by asynchronous error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, error-handling

I'm trying to handle all my errors in my backend in a streamlined fashion. In one of my endpoints I save some documents to my mongoose database and if there are any errors, I catch them and propagate them to my error handler by calling `next(err)`. This works for errors outside the Promise, but not when `next()` is called inside the `catch()` clause. My endpoint is defined like this:

```js
router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
    let listToAdd = req.body;

    if (!(listToAdd instanceof Array)) {
        listToAdd = [listToAdd];
    }

    let persons = listToAdd.map(p => {
        return new Person(p)
    });

    Promise.all(persons.map(p => p.save()))
        .then(saved => {
            res.status(201).send(`Successfully saved document(s) with id(s): ${persons.map(p => p._id.toString())}`)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            next(err);  // This error never reaches my middleware
        });
    next();  // errors here be handled by middleware
});
```

My **app.js**, where my middleware is registered:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

// Routes
const personalFileRouter = require("./endpoints/person");
const userRouter = require("./endpoints/user");

// Custom Middleware
const {myRequestLoggingMiddleware} = require("./middleware/express_logging");
const {myErrorLoggingMiddleware} = require("./middleware/express_logging");

// Create a new express app
const app = express();

// Use CORS to allow communication to frontend
app.use(cors());

// use bodyparser to parse url body
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Use Express Sessions to track user logins
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
  })
}));

// Whenever we get a request on the form "/whatever" it should use the routes file to redirect
app.use("/person/", personalFileRouter);
app.use("/user/", userRouter);

app.use(myErrorLoggingMiddleware);  // <-- Register my middleware last

module.exports = app;
```

And finally, my middleware error handler

```js
function myErrorLoggingMiddleware(err, req, res, next) {  // Never reached :(
    if (res.headersSent) {
        return next(err)
    }

    if (err instanceof mongoose.Error.ValidationError) {
        validationErrorHandler(err, req, res);
    } else {
        defaultErrorHandler(err, req, res);
    }
    next();
}

exports.myErrorLoggingMiddleware = myErrorLoggingMiddleware;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is embarrassing. I'm not a 100% sure why, but I reckon that when I call `next()` below my promise, which is executed before the promise is resolved, the function has run its course and next is "used up". So when the promise later resolves, `next()` is an empty function that does not reference any middleware. My solution is then to simply remove the last `next()` and **only** call next inside my promise.